# How to inspect variables on the fly

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, unity-game-engine

I installed the Unity Tools for Visual Studio.

Now I created a variable `x` which is incremented on every frame at the `Update` function.

```
private int x = 0;

void Update()
{
    x++;
}
```

However, if I go to visual studio and press "Attach to unity and play" and then hover over `x` at `x++` then I don't see any value.

[image]

If I right click on `x` then there is no option `add watch` or similar.

[image: no add watch]

I can only see the value if I set a breakpoint, but then I have to hit `continue` after every frame.

[image]

Is it possible to add a watch and see the value how it is updating live while I play? Otherwise I have to add many `Debug.Log()` statements everywhere in my code for each variable which I need to watch, but I don't think that this is the intended way.

There is an [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/07/15/7-ways-to-look-at-the-values-of-variables-while-debugging-in-visual-studio/) where the author says:

> When I was in school the first way I learned how to debug a wonky
>   application was by sticking “print()” statements all over the place,
>   running my code, and looking back through the log of output seeing if
>   I noticed that something looked wrong. Then if I wanted to look at the
>   value of another variable I would have to add a new “print()”
>   statement, recompile, and re-run the application again. This can be a
>   tedious process, so I am pleased to tell you there is a better way
>   than littering your code with a slew of “print()” statements you’ll
>   have to remove later. **You can use the tools of the Visual Studio
>   debugger to inspect variables on the fly.**

But this does not seem to be true.

Comment: Consider your application will run at 50 to 100fps. You will need a damn sharp eye to see those values changing. So blocking kinda has to be.

Comment: That was only an example. In my real application the values are not changing that fast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't inspect variables without pausing at a breakpoint. Alternatively you can observe them in Unity's inspector. To do so:

- Switch the inspector to debug mode (right click on the tab)
- Set it public temporarily
- Use the [[SerializeField] attribute](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html) temporarily

Comment: Thank you. So basically that article was just clickbaiting me and it is not possible to inspect on the fly? Or does it normally work but not in connection with unity?

Comment: I think it won't work on the fly. To evaluate a variable the debugger would have to stop.

Comment: It should be clarified that "on the fly" != "realtime". That's what breakpoints are for. Add a break point, and a 'watch' on the variable you're monitoring, ta-da! Pause and start as you see fit... Step through the code. Then, profit!

Failing that, use a conditional breakpoint, so it's only triggered if x == y etc.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work with visual studio, you need to use Debug.Log() for every variable which you need to track.

```
void Update()
{
    x++;
    Debug.Log(x);
}
```

Comment: That does not answer the problem. His last part mentions why he does not want to print. And printing in Update? For real?